# acceptAndOpen() method error

Tags: java, bluetooth, service-discovery

I am making a bluetooth related application to browse the internet.. With Server as laptop/desktop and client as the mobile phone.. i need to establish a connection between client and server.. but the execution of the server suddenly stops at the method `acceptAndOpen()` .. Please help to solve the problem.. this is the code where it stops in the server side:

```
while (mServerState) {
    StreamConnection btConn = null;
    try {
        updateStatus("[server:] Now waiting for a client to connect");

        //here is the error
        btConn = (StreamConnection) btServerNotifier.acceptAndOpen();

        RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(btConn);


        System.out.println("Remote device address: " + dev.getBluetoothAddress());

        updateStatus("Remote device " + dev.getFriendlyName(true) + "connected");

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }
    if (btConn != null) {
        processConnection(btConn);
    }
}
```

Comment: - do you use bluecove library? (it looks like)
 - what does `updateStatus()` function does? only prints output?
 - i think you should update your question, make it better :)